# Is ajax request slowing down the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to send ajax requests and do GUI animation in the same time(about 150 requests in a second). It's fine when I doing the first time, and the animation becomes laggy even I refresh the page or restart the browser.

Therefore I tried removing everything in ajax callback, but the browser still acts very laggy while waiting responses. I also tried jquery $.get, and set async to 'true', but the problem still exists.

However, if I change ajax to websocket, this problem is solved. Is that means, ajax requests send by js affect performance? I want to figure this out, thanks!

code :

```
var i = 0;
var f = setInterval(function(){
    // url is an array
    addItem(url[i]);
    i++;
    if(i >=url.length) clearInterval(f);
},33);

// send ajax requests
function addItem(url){
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open('GET',url,true);           
        xml.send();
        xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status==200){ 
                // do nothing
            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: `about 150 requests in a second` whatever is your issue, that comes from here... And ya, you should use websockets for  bi-directional web communication

Comment: 150 animation calls a second or http requests?

Comment: both animation(SVG) and requests.

Comment: That's never going to fly, there's no way the browser can keep up with that interval, it's going to crash any browser

Comment: Why do you need so many requests?

Comment: requesting 150 response in a 33millisecond can make borwser laggy. You can use real time like node js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

150 requests/second seems like bad design. You need to group your requests and send fewer. The animation makes it worse. I believe there is no valid explanation to have this many requests. Yes, you can switch to WebSocket, but make sure your communication does not duplicate messages and does not send multiple messages which could be sent as a single message.